# How can I implement a SQL Update that I can roll back?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to execute this SQL Statement but I am not 100% sure if it will work correctly.

```
MERGE [dbo].[Word] as target
USING [dbo].[AWL] as source
ON target.[WordId] = source.[col1]
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [AWL570Sublist] = col2;
```

Is there a way I can start a transaction, do the MERGE, check it worked and then rollback or commit from the SQL Query window?

Comment: What are you asking? All (almost) statements can be rolled back if you enclose them in a transaction. Are you asking to to use `BEGIN TRAN`/`ROLLBACK TRAN`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "check it worked"? `MERGE` is atomic which means that any errors thrown by it will cause a rollback

Answer (score 1):

With rollback on error:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    MERGE [dbo].[Word] as target
    USING [dbo].[AWL] as source
    ON target.[WordId] = source.[col1]
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET [AWL570Sublist] = col2;

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0) BEGIN
        PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN 1
    END

COMMIT TRAN
RETURN 0
```

Good [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling) with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

MERGE [dbo].[Word] as target
USING [dbo].[AWL] as source
ON target.[WordId] = source.[col1]
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [AWL570Sublist] = col2;

-- Other statements

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Be aware that if your actions cause identity columns to increment, then the rollback will NOT reset the next identity value to it's value at the start of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
   BEGIN TRY;
   BEGIN TRAN;

        MERGE [dbo].[Word] as target
        USING [dbo].[AWL] as source
        ON target.[WordId] = source.[col1]
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET [AWL570Sublist] = col2;  

    IF @@ERROR = 0
  BEGIN
      COMMIT TRAN;
  END
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @@ERROR AS ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [Error Description]
  ROLLBACK TRAN;
  END CATCH
```